# Which base to use to calculate profit of sold product?

Tags: calculation, profit

Let's say I want to sell shoes, which cost me 90€ in production, and I want to sell them with 20% profit.
Do I calculate my selling price then with 90€ * 1,2 (profit is 20% of costs) or with 90€/0.8 (profit is 20% of selling price)?

So do I calculate the profit from the costs of from my selling price?

Comment: Be careful with terminology, "profit" is not precise. If you mean Gross Profit Margin of 20% then it is the latter calculation that is used; the former calculation where if you tack on 20% to costs is called a 20% Markup.

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/102714/whats-difference-between-profit-margin-and-markup.asp For Gross Profit Margin it is Revenue (not Cost) that is the base.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Quant-related imo.

Comment: Surely not quant-related, but intriguing. Why would 90€/0.8 make any sense?

Comment: @SuavestArt 90/0.8 calculated the price when you want to have 20% gross profit margin based on the selling price. 90/0.8 = 112.5 and 20% of 112.5 is 22.5. So you have costs of 90€ (80% of selling price) and 22.5 gross profit (or how you want to call it) and thats 20% of the selling price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to *markup pricing* and *margin-based pricing*, which are distinct pricing strategies.

In *margin-based pricing*, we're concerned about the difference between the product's selling price and its cost.

$\frac{(P_{selling} - P_{cost})}{P_{selling}} = 1 - \frac{P_{cost}}{P_{selling}}= Margin_{percent} $

$ 1 - Margin_{percent} = \frac{P_{cost}}{P_{selling}} $

$P_{selling} = \frac{P_{cost}}{1 - Margin_{percent}}$

Which relates to your second calculation of 'profit'.
Your first calculation is the markup, which is a fixed percentage of the cost.

When it is appropriate using each pricing strategy seems to be a business management question, which is briefly discussed [here](https://brixx.com/markup-vs-margin-differences/)